# Extracting Particular String in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract or just retain certain characters from a varying string using SQL in Oracle. I used the SUBSTR function but that does not work for all the cases.

Example: Values are like this:

```
B2B_BID-XSKU957109
B2B_BID-SKU340535
B2B-SKU342345
B2B_BID-SKU340020201
```

Results I want:

```
SKU957109
SKU340535
SKU342345
SKU340020201
```

So its just not the last 10 characters but I want only the part which has the string 'SKU' and the number following it. I have given all kind of examples I have. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you define the part you want? The second and last seem to lack everything before the last dash. What about the first one? Or do you always want to only take the last ten characters?

Comment: Ok. I added another example. So its just not the last 10 characters but I want only the part which has SKU and the number following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed token

If the token you're trying to extract is fixed length and always at the same place, you can use the [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) function with negative index:

```
select substr('123456',-1,6) from dual;

S
-
6

select substr('123456',-6,6) from dual;

SUBSTR
------
123456
```

In your case it seems the token has variable length, though.

### Variable Length Token

If the string you're trying to extract is not fix, you can't do it with traditional SQL or with the simple `substr` function. You could use [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm). In this latter case, except if you *really* need for some exotic reason to treat your string in Oracle, I'd suggest you to do that in the **application** instead (or to double check *carefully* the regexp hit on Oracle performances).

#### Proposed Solution

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('B2B_BID-SKU340020201','SKU[0-9]+') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want with `substr()`, `instr()`, and `reverse()`:

```
select substr(val, 1-instr(reverse(val), '-'))
from (select 'B2B_BID-XSKU957109' as val from dual) t
```

The above seemed to answer a slightly different question about getting the stuff after the last `-`.  To get the stuff with the last `SKU`:

```
select substr(val, instr(val, 'SKU'))
from (select 'B2B_BID-XSKU957109' as val from dual) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32086) is a little SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Yes. I wanted the stuff with the last SKU. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot Gordon!

Comment: Good one, though I think the solution with regexp is more compact and less demanding in terms of performance (no nested select). It is worth giving a look at the query explanation tool...

Comment: Oh yea! This is for few million records and its taking a little time. Will run the explain plan and I think I might use the regexp method and check the performance on that one too ! Thanks Alex